# Confluent Kafka producer message format for nested records

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-kafka-python

I have a AVRO schema registered in a kafka topic and am trying to send data to it. The schema has nested records and I'm not sure how I correctly send data to it using confluent_kafka python.

**Example schema:** *ingore any typos in schema (real one is very large, just an example)

```
 {
 "namespace": "company__name",
 "name": "our_data",
 "type": "record",
 "fields": [
           {
            "name": "datatype1",
            "type": ["null", {
                 "type": "record",
                 "name": "datatype1_1",
                 "fields": [ 
                     {"name": "site", "type": "string"},
                     {"name": "units", "type": "string"}
                  ]
             }]
             "default": null
            }
            {
            "name": "datatype2",
            "type": ["null", {
                 "type": "record",
                 "name": "datatype2_1",
                 "fields": [ 
                     {"name": "site", "type": "string"},
                     {"name": "units", "type": "string"}
                  ]
             }]
             "default": null
            }
           ]
          }
```

I am trying to send data to this schema using confluent_kafka python version. When I have done this prior, the records were not nested and I would use a typical dictionary `key: value` pairs and serialize it. How can I send nested data to work with schema.

What I tried so far...

```
message = {'datatype1': 
            {'site': 'sitename',
             'units': 'm'
            }
           }
```

this version does not cause any kafka errors, but the all of the columns show up as null

and...

```
message = {'datatype1': 
            {'datatype1_1':
              {'site': 'sitename',
               'units': 'm'
              }
            }
           }
```

This version produced a kafka error with the schema.

Comment: You are missing quotes on `datatype1` and `datatype1_1` in your Python dict, so that is not valid code, but what was the error from the registry or Kafka?

Comment: Sorry, that was just an typo when writing the question. Just fixed in the question. KafkaError{code=_VALUE_SERIALIZATION,val=-161,str="{'datatype1_1':{'site': 'sitename', 'units': 'm'}" (type <class 'dict'>) do not match  (the schema)

Comment: Is this JSON or binary?

Comment: And have you tried if it works when datatype1_1 is not nullable?

Answer (score 0):

If you use namespaces, you don't have to worry about naming collisions and you can properly structure your optional records:
for example, both

```
{
  "meta": {
    "instanceID": "something"
  }
}
```

And

```
{}
```

are valid instances of:

```
{
  "doc": "Survey",
  "name": "Survey",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "meta",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "name": "meta",
          "type": "record",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "instanceID",
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ],
              "namespace": "Survey.meta"
            }
          ],
          "namespace": "Survey"
        }
      ],
      "namespace": "Survey"
    }
  ]
}
```